# Array of arrays contains array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

this might be a duplicate but I couldn't find a solution.  If I have an array of arrays, is there a "built-in" way to determine if that array of arrays includes another array.  `Array.prototype.includes()` helps, but doesn't get me all the way because of (I think) object references as shown below.  I can manually test equality of each value but I'm sure there's a better way.

```
$ node
> b = [[1,2,3]]
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
> b[0]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> b.includes(b[0])
true
> b.includes([1,2,3])
false
>
```

Comment: direct comparison.  Does b contain the exact array [1,2,3]?

Comment: Note that in JavaScript `[1,2,3] !== [1,2,3]`. They are different arrays.

Comment: Well the answer is there already but I would use .toString() instead

Comment: @Saurav Is .toString() more performant?

Comment: `.toString()` would not work really with nested array (e.g. `[1,2,[3,4]].toString() == [[1],2,[3],[[4]]].toString()`. 
 Or when the array contains `,` (`[1,'2,3'].toString()==[1,2,3].toString()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use `JSON.stringify & includes`.

```js
JSON.stringify([[1,2,3]]).includes(JSON.stringify([1,2,3]))
true
JSON.stringify([[1,3]]).includes(JSON.stringify([1,2,3]))
false
```

Comment: While this may be a quick and dirty solution, this has some pitfalls. To give an example: `JSON.stringify([[_ => 0]]).includes(JSON.stringify([null]))`

Comment: @ASDFGerte you are right, but it's only a case where the array contains functions. It's safe to use if he can assume the array contains only numbers.